# Dynamic User Control

Tags: c#

I've been thinking of creating a simple CMS system in C#, and the first problem that came to mind is the integration of user controls dynamicly.

Usualy i've been integrating user controls on each page staticly, where i've registered the name of my user control.

In this project i've been thinking about assigning modules (user controls) to my content pages, through my database.

Now my question is how i can integrate one and perhabs multiple user controls dynamicly on a single page.

Comment: Is this using WinForms, WPF, ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Placeholder and assigning a dynamic Control to it seemed like a valid approach.

```
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ControlInstance);
```